# delphi DBGrid cell not empty

Tags: database, delphi, dbgrid

In my form, i have a TDBGRid, TDatasource , MessageTable and 2 button. I have a button to add new row in my DBGRID :

```
MessageTable.Append;
MessageTable.Edit;
MessageTable.FieldByName('FieldName').AsString  :=  sName;
MessageTable.Post;
```

The second button  is used to delete a current row :

```
MessageTable.Edit ;
MessageTable.Delete ;
```

How can ensure all Cell not empty before the post?

If there is an  empty Cell, i need to ignore this row !

how can I do that?

Comment: You don't need the Edit line. After append the table is in dsinsert state and you can assign values. You also don't need to set the table in dsedit state before delete

Comment: Please be more specific with your problem: you can fill all fields in the beforepost event or you can set fields to predefined values in the afterinsert event. 
What means empty cell? you can exclude data records from the grid in the ondrawdatacell event or you can check in the beforepost event if all fields are filled (<> NULL depends on your database)

Comment: **I have a `button` to add new row in my DBGRID :** You can use that `button OnClick event` do all the validity of the data. `No valid Data` no `MessageTable.Append` .....Why to call `MessageTable.Append` with not valid data? And catch it in `beforePost event` pointless.

Comment: Use persistent fields (defined by double-clicking your table or query on the form, and then adding fields). If you do so, you can use the `TField.Required` property - setting it to True means that the field has to have content before a Post.

Comment: it's very unclear what you need. You should edit your question.

Comment: @ChristineRoss thank you.. Actually, i use the button add to add new empty row(all filed are null).. when click out of the dbgrid.. my row is saved in my table.. i need to ensure all data saved not null.. how can do that? and with any event to do that? .. 
it may be that my code is wrong .. and I hope that my need is clear

Comment: @moskito-x thank you for you reply..  I'm beginner with database with Delphi .. after your recommendation, I made a mistake. when i click on the add button, I want to add an empty row to be populated later. When I click outside my DBGrid, i want remove this row not full.

Comment: @KenWhite thank you.. I will try your solution

Comment: @GabrielF thank you.. Next step, i will update my post correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the features the dataset (in this case, TTable) already give you instead of trying to reinvent the wheel. TDataSet provides an event (OnBeforePost) that is specifically designed for this purpose.

Click on your `TTable`, and then switch to the Events tab in the Object Inspector. Find the `OnBeforePost` event and double click it to generate the event shell in the Code Editor. You'll see something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Table1BeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  // DataSet is the TDataSet (TTable, TQuery, TADOQuery, etc.) to which
  // event is attached
end;
```

You can do all of your validations needed before a record is actually written to the database here. For instance, if you want to make sure every single field has something in it, you can do this:

```
procedure TForm1.Table1BeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // You can replace DataSet with your actual table variable name, but using it 
  // this way allows you to use this same event for more than one table if you want.
  for i := 0 to DataSet.FieldCount - 1 do
    if DataSet.Fields[i].IsNull then
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Field %s has no value', DataSet.Fields[i].FieldName);
end;
```

If you want to make sure only certain fields have values, or that the value is within a certain range, you can access the field directly:

```
procedure TForm1.Table1BeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if DataSet.FieldByName('MyField').IsNull then
    Abort;  // This silently cancels the post without telling the user    
  if DataSet.FieldByName('AField').AsInteger = 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('AField must not be 0');
end;
```

Now you don't have to do anything at all in your TDBGrid. If the user hits <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> on the last row and a new row is inserted, and they enter incomplete or wrong data, the events above will take care of it. They'll also work if you use two buttons (one to insert or edit and the other to post), because the events will handle everything else.

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonInsertClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Table1.Insert;  // Or Append - if you have an index on the table they're the same thing
end;

procedure TForm1.ButtonPostClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Table1.Post;   // This is 100% of the code you need here
end;
```